# Unexpected segfault in a grep command

Tags: regex, git, grep, segmentation-fault

Why does the following grep command segfault:

```
grep -Pz "(.|\n)*" *
```

For the command to segfault, it must be run in a directory with files containing text. Without the or group, it does not seg-fault.

Comment: As the man page says, `grep -P` is "highly experimental" so YMMV and use at your own risk. I personally would avoid it like the plague given that clear warning from the authors but I see other people advocate it...

Comment: Are you trying to match on period or "any character but line terminators"? My assumption is that you are trying to match on a period at the end of a sentence OR a newline. In your example regex, the period will match basically everything, where as to match the period as text, you will need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Maybe your _grep_ is really a virus.

Comment: What does `grep -Ez “(.|\n)*” *` do? That regexp isn't PCRE-specific so that will tell you if the issue is related to using `-P` or not. The regexp also doesn't make sense but that's another problem and shouldn't cause a segfault.

Comment: I simplified the regex down from what I was using:
`grep -Pz "foo\(.*\).*(?!(.|\n)*bar)" *`
I essentially wanted a regex for finding files in which the foo method is called, but the bar method is not.
The funky thing is grep segfaults _after_ completing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the following grep command segfault

Because there is a bug in it.

Any crash in user utilities, such as `grep`, `cp`, `ls`, etc. is a *bug* in said utility, and you should report it with a set of minimal steps required to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems similar to another bug: "`git grep`" compiled with `libpcre2` sometimes triggered a segfault.
And with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), this is being fixed.

See [commit a25b908](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a25b9085043b8029169b4d5b172b78ca3f38fb37), [commit ce9a257](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce9a257031ca1cf3496c5bb1cd0d4b5ecb8379f2) (23 Nov 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b3f04e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3f04e5b4c7e04d70e4cef74b4848dd198653cbb), 13 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### `grep`: fix segfault under `-P + PCRE2 <=10.30 + (*NO_JIT)`

> Fix a bug in the compilation of PCRE2 patterns under JIT (the most common runtime configuration). Any pattern with a `(*NO_JIT)` verb would
> segfault in any currently released PCRE2 version:
>
> ```
> $ git grep -P '(*NO_JIT)hi.*there'
>  Segmentation fault
> ```
>
> That this segfaulted was a bug in PCRE2 itself, after reporting it ("[How am I supposed to use PCRE2 JIT in the face of (*NO_JIT) ?](https://lists.exim.org/lurker/thread/20171123.101502.7f0d38ca.en.html)") on `pcre-dev`, it's been fixed in a yet-to-be-released version of PCRE (presumably released first as 10.31).
> Now it'll die with:
>
> ```
> $ git grep -P '(*NO_JIT)hi.*there'
>  fatal: pcre2_jit_match failed with error code -45: bad JIT option
> ```
>
> But the cause of the bug is in our own code dating back to my
> [94da919](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94da9193a6eb8f1085d611c04ff8bbb4f5ae1e0a) ("`grep`: add support for PCRE v2", 2017-06-01, Git 2.14-rc0).
>
> As explained at more length in the comment being added here, it isn't
> sufficient to just check `pcre2_config()` to see whether the JIT should
> be used, `pcre2_pattern_info()` also has to be asked.
>
> This is something I discovered myself when fiddling around with PCRE2
> verbs in patterns passed to git. I don't expect that any user of git
> has encountered this given the obscurity of passing PCRE2 verbs
> through to the library, along with the relative obscurity of (*NO_JIT)
> itself.

Again, that might not be exactly the same bug, but you might consider testing your `git grep` again once Git 2.16 is release, to see if the issue persists.

---

Git 2.22.1 (Q3 2019) fixes another potential segfault.

See [commit de99eb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de99eb0c24d96730de187edd37b9ca9d42b0b05d) (23 May 2019) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 518e874](https://github.com/git/git/commit/518e8748979dbe485f519d0f63c3642cc1643f79), 25 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `grep`: fail if call could output and name is null

> `grep_source()`, which performs much of the work for Git's grep library,
> allows passing an arbitrary struct `grep_source` which represents the text
> which `grep_source()` should search to match a pattern in the provided
> struct `grep_opt`.
> In most callers, the `grep_source::name` field is set to an appropriate prefix to print before a colon when a result matches:
>
> ```
> README:Git is an Open Source project covered by the GNU General
> ```
>
> One caller, `grep_buffer()`, leaves the `grep_source::name` field set to
> `NULL` because there isn't enough context to determine an appropriate name
> for this kind of output line.
> In practice, this has been fine: the only caller of `grep_buffer()` is "`git log --grep`", and that caller sets `grep_opt::status_only`, which disables output and only checks whether a match exists.
> But this is brittle: a future caller can call `grep_buffer()` without `grep_opt::status_only` set, and as soon as it hits a match, `grep_source()` will try to print the match and segfault:
>
> ```
> (null):Git is an Open Source project covered by the GNU General
> ```
>
> For example, a future caller might want to print all matching lines from
> commits which match a regex.
>
> Futureproof by diagnosing early a use of the API that could trigger that
> condition, before we know whether the pattern matches:
>
> ```
> BUG: grep.c:1783: grep call which could print a name requires
>   grep_source.name be non-NULL
> Aborted
> ```
>
> This way, the caller's author gets an indication of how to fix the issue
>
> - by providing `grep_source::name` or `setting grep_opt::status_only`
> - and they are warned of the potential for a segfault unconditionally, rather than only if there is a match.

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) makes sure that PCRE v2 only is involved, when using JIT.

See [commit ff61681](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff61681b46760f6a64353018760bccc14c90f8e9), [commit 8991da6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8991da6a3864d93d860afe4c510b4fdbf0da6363) (25 Aug 2019) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 93424f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93424f1f7d790944168d46faf5222a388898d031), 11 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### grep: make sure `NO_LIBPCRE1_JIT` disable `JIT` in `PCRE1`

[e87de7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e87de7cab4f4e3a8ebf4cc588d26636c3d828e4c) ("`grep`: un-break building with PCRE < 8.32", 2017-05-25, Git v2.14.0-rc0) added a restriction for JIT support that is no longer needed after
`pcre_jit_exec()` calls were removed.

---

Also with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), `git grep` fixes a memory leak.

See [commit 10da030](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10da030ab757c38a01507bf18e2484698000b791), [commit 513f2b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/513f2b0bbd47015640723a10210c527839e8946a), [commit 57d4660](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57d4660468ef2674bb6afc2c5814d4b397a5eda9) (16 Oct 2019) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e0ff2d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0ff2d4c7ec338e30ea5e0340cda7f5fe8a187dc), 23 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/513f2b0bbd47015640723a10210c527839e8946a): make PCRE2 aware of custom allocator
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> [94da9193a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94da9193a6eb8f1085d611c04ff8bbb4f5ae1e0a) ("`grep`: add support for PCRE v2", 2017-06-01, Git v2.14.0-rc -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0ff2d4c7ec338e30ea5e0340cda7f5fe8a187dc) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d81542e6f3632d1a6185a4e629fade0641f9688b)) didn't include a way to override the system allocator, and so it is incompatible with custom allocators (e.g. `nedmalloc`).
> This problem became obvious when we tried to plug a memory leak by `free()`ing a data structure allocated by PCRE2, triggering a segfault in Windows (where we use `nedmalloc` by default).
>
> PCRE2 requires the use of a general context to override the allocator and therefore, there is a lot more code needed than in PCRE1, including a couple of wrapper functions.
>
> Extend the grep API with a "destructor" that could be called to cleanup any objects that were created and used globally.
>
> Update [`builtin/grep.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/513f2b0bbd47015640723a10210c527839e8946a/builtin/grep.c) to use that new API, but any other future users should make sure to have matching `grep_init()`/`grep_destroy()` calls if they are using the pattern matching functionality.
>
> Move some of the logic that was before done per thread (in the workers) into an earlier phase to avoid degrading performance, but as the use of PCRE2 with custom allocators is better understood it is expected more of its functions will be instructed to use the custom allocator as well as was done in the [original code this work was based on](https://public-inbox.org/git/3397e6797f872aedd18c6d795f4976e1c579514b.1565005867.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/).

---

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), there are now updates to memory allocation code around the use of pcre2 library.

See [commit c176035](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1760352e0b27cfbdffd97dec50a9eb552318993), [commit cbe81e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbe81e653fa1adc6b4e09d881628074f7448289a), [commit 8d12851](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d1285134297d66638f615cb076d1964e2dbbc19), [commit b76bf27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b76bf27f6a0138f66f7cfca122b7ddc68836160d), [commit 797c359](https://github.com/git/git/commit/797c359978eb13ddff10974a6c6469e33695606c), [commit a39b400](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a39b4003f0e4515da5d88480c24ec27196dabfb7), [commit 588e4fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/588e4fb19190c03319a2b67d447dd40f97d85531), [commit 47eebd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47eebd2fd2c576377f40555c539c5fc56af060a0), [commit 1cfc5a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cfc5a850c3962f341accb15cef6d09c21bbbdee), [commit 0ddf8ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ddf8ceac0b38c1ec89551c08dc49cb4b96c82bc) (18 Feb 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 24119d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24119d9d7b686f8f4ad5ac91fab32fd3d4bb67f1), 22 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`grep/pcre2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d1285134297d66638f615cb076d1964e2dbbc19): actually make pcre2 use custom allocator
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Continue work started in [513f2b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/513f2b0bbd47015640723a10210c527839e8946a) ("`grep`: make PCRE2 aware of custom allocator", 2019-10-16, Git v2.24.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0ff2d4c7ec338e30ea5e0340cda7f5fe8a187dc) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d81542e6f3632d1a6185a4e629fade0641f9688b)) and make PCREv2 use our `pcre2_{malloc,free}()`.
> functions for allocation.
> We'll now use it for all PCREv2 allocations.
>
> Before this patch we'd on e.g.:
>
> ```
> grep --threads=1 -iP æ.*var.*xyz
> ```
>
> Only use `pcre2_{malloc,free}()` for 2 `malloc()` calls and 2 corresponding `free()` calls.
> Now it's 12 calls to each.
> This can be observed with the `GREP_PCRE2_DEBUG_MALLOC` debug mode.

(more details in [that commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d1285134297d66638f615cb076d1964e2dbbc19))

---

"[`git grep --and -e foo`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1157618a2ae50ae611ca22ce1833760bc0456156/Documentation/git-grep.txt#L271)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---and))</sup> ought to have been diagnosed as an error but instead segfaulted, which has been corrected with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021).

See [commit fe7fe62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe7fe62d8da0949d9b2bca34467b349bd294e91b) (30 Jun 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1157618](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1157618a2ae50ae611ca22ce1833760bc0456156), 13 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe7fe62d8da0949d9b2bca34467b349bd294e91b): report missing left operand of `--and`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Matthew Hughes</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Git grep allows combining two patterns with `--and`.
> It checks and reports if the second pattern is missing when compiling the expression.
> A missing first pattern, however, is only reported later at match time.
> Thus no error is returned if no matching is done, e.g. because no file matches the also given pathspec.
>
> When that happens we get an expression tree with an `GREP_NODE_AND` node and a `NULL` pointer to the missing left child.
> `free_pattern_expr()` tries to dereference it during the cleanup at the end, which results in a segmentation fault.
>
> Fix this by verifying the presence of the left operand at expression compilation time.

---

The pathspec code carelessly dereferenced `NULL` while emitting an error message, which has been corrected with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023).

See [commit b1688ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1688ea02df6fdefd5a228a0d52583356d433a99) (20 Oct 2023) by [Kristoffer Haugsbakk (`LemmingAvalanche`)](https://github.com/LemmingAvalanche).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 64912cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64912cc0239fc563978e58520c5ed9e802eb61e6), 30 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1688ea02df6fdefd5a228a0d52583356d433a99): die gracefully when outside repository
>
> <sup>Reported-by: ks1322 ks1322</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kristoffer Haugsbakk</sup>

> Die gracefully when [`git grep --no-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b1688ea02df6fdefd5a228a0d52583356d433a99/Documentation/git-grep.txt#L48)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---no-index))</sup> is run outside of a Git repository and the path is outside the directory tree.
>
> If you are not in a Git repository and say:
>
> ```
> git grep --no-index search ..
> ```
>
> You trigger a `BUG`:
>
> ```
> BUG: environment.c:213: git environment hasn't been setup
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```
>
> Because `..` is a valid path which is treated as a pathspec.
> Then `pathspec` figures out that it is not in the current directory tree.
> The `BUG` is triggered when `pathspec` tries to advise the user about how the path is not in the current (non-existing) repository.